# Mock alert as side effect of a function with Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm trying to learn testing in general and Jest in particular.
I'm going through strange cases just to have an idea of how to handle them.

I have this super basic example. A function that takes a string and if the string is hello it alerts it.

```
function alertHello(input='') {
  if (input === 'hello') alert(input)
}
```

I want to test the alert.
I checked some StackOverflow posts where the suggestion is to mock it

```
jest.spyOn(window, 'alert').mockImplementation(() => {});
```

But I cannot still understand how to implement it.
Any help and advice will be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? The snippet with spyOn is the exact way this should be done.

Comment: Thanks for your concern, Estus Flask. I don't know how to implement it or put the pieces together. I will appreciate help :)

Comment: It's implemented this way. And there should have been an example of how it's used where you pasted it from. You can do `alertHello(''hello'); expect(alert).toBeCalledWith('hello')`.